# How can I make form controls be reactive in a "write back" manner?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say I have two text input fields whose values are reactive associated to a set's name and description:

```
{{#with set}}
<input type="text" id="set_name" value="{{name}}" placeholder="Untitled Set"/>
<input type="text" id="set_desc" value="{{description}}" placeholder="Add Description"/>
{{/with}}
```

Currently, when the user changes the input field, I have to add code to manually update the Set's attributes e.g. (in CoffeeScript)

```
update = (set, field, newVal)->
  newVal = $.trim(newVal)
  if newVal && set[field] != newVal
    keyVal = {}
    keyVal[field] = newVal
    Sets.update(_id:set._id, {$set:keyVal})

Template.cardSubmit.events
  'change #set_name': (evt)->
    update(this, 'name', evt.target.value)
  'change #set_desc': (evt)->
    update(this, 'description', evt.target.value)
```

This gets pretty repetitive after a while. Is there a way to this declaratively in Meteor? If not, any suggestions how to extend Meteor to allow for such 2-way reactivity?

Knockout.js has a neat way of doing this (of course just on the client side): http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Comment: It's on the roadmap -- https://trello.com/card/easy-forms/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/8 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUW8kxpze0Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *two-way data binding.* As @emgee notes, it's not natively supported in Meteor (yet). That said, you can extend Meteor with packages that add it in one way or another:

- [Handlebar-bind](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-bind) is specifically designed to add two-way data binding support to Handlebars templates. See in the instructions about `liveUpdate:true`. Beware though that the package describes itself as in "early sneak peek test state".
- [Angular.js for Meteor](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs) adds the Angular framework to Meteor. This is a more radical solution that will more or less replace Handlebars with Angular.js' templates which support two-way data-binding. Though while Angular itself is mature, its implementation in Meteor is similarly alpha at this point.